# Date format conversion `dd-mm-yyyy` to `yyyy-mm-dd` from in mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am converting date format in my table column `date` from `dd-mm-yyyy` to `yyyy-mm-dd` (to MySQL database conversion).

```
date_format(str_to_date("date",'%d-%b-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

In database table `date` column value can have `01-01-1987` or `01-01-87`. So if date column value is `01-01-1987` `(YYYY)` then its working fine. It is not working if date value is `01-01-87` `(YY)` and date will be updated as null.

**See below procedure code:**

```
SET @oQry = CONCAT("UPDATE ",importTable," as t1 JOIN ( SELECT id,date_format(str_to_date(",@date_fields,",'%d-%b-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') as date_formate FROM ",importTable," ) as t2 ON t1.id = t2.id set t1.",@date_fields," = t2.date_formate");
```

Can anyone suggest how can we handle it if date value is in `01-01-87` `(YY)`.

Comment: You can use a simple case statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lowercase version ('y') is for two-digit years and the uppercase ('Y') is for four-digit years. https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-date_format-function.php

So try this:

```
select str_to_date('01-01-87','%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: Calling `date_format` is not required when you are applying `str_to_date`.

Comment: `str_to_date('01-01-87','%d-%m-%y')` is just enough

Comment: @RavinderReddy but we are talking about format conversion. See the question above

Comment: return data type of `str_to_date` function is `date` whose format by default is `yyyy-mm-dd`. so explicit use of `date_format` is not required on the returned value.

Comment: But date can be '01-01-87' or '01-01-1987'...so how can we handle both case?

Comment: The problem is, the op doesn't know whether it's 87 or 1987. That was the nub of the question

Comment: `select str_to_date('01-01-1987','%d-%m-%Y')` works for both case (edited)